# PhantomJS doesn't respect SVG color-interpolation-filters

Tags: svg, phantomjs, qtwebkit, color-space, svg-filters

I have an SVG with two images. These images have [`feComponentTransfer`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/svg/elements/feComponentTransfer) applied to them.
For these images, [`color-interpolation-filters`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#ColorInterpolationFiltersProperty) is set to `linearRGB` and `sRGB`, correspondingly:

**http://jsfiddle.net/9eU37/6/**

Here's how it renders in Safari and Chrome:

[image]

(linearRGB on the left, sRGB on the right)

Here's how PhantomJS renders it:

[image]

(linearRGB on the left, sRGB on the right)

As you can see, PhantomJS seems to **ignore `color-interpolation-filters`** (there is no difference between the two images). Another odd thing is that the resulting image matches neither sRGB nor linearRGB browser version.

Is there anything I can do it make it render SVG like the browser does, and respect the setting?

Comment: Chrome/Mac has same behavior as PhantomJS

Comment: @Michael: I'm using Chrome/Mac 31.0.1650.63. What's your version?

Comment: Same version - but I have GPU acceleration of filters disabled in Chrome://flags - that might be the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do your own gamma correction manually by using an feComponentTransfer type=gamma. Usually a 2.2 for the exponent will do it.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I tried to do, but in the end I decided to dump Phantom and use [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/status.html) that works great and has less footprint.